# Python urllib2: Reading content body even during HTTPError exception?

Tags: python

I'm using urllib2 to fetch a a page via HTTP.  Sometimes the resource throws a HTTP error 400 (Bad Request) when my request contains an error.  However, that response also contains an XML element that gives a detailed error message.  It would be very handy to be able to see that error rather than just the HTTPError exception returned by urllib2.

How do I return the document contents in spite of the exception?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57751865/8521548

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can treat the error as a response.

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#httperror

> When an error is raised the server
>   responds by returning an HTTP error
>   code and an error page. You can use
>   the HTTPError instance as a response
>   on the page returned. This means that
>   as well as the code attribute, it also
>   has read, geturl, and info, methods.

Answer (score 93):

```
import urllib2
try:
    request = urllib2.Request('http://www.somesite.com')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    error_message = e.read()
    print error_message
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `read` the response message from the HTTPError exception.

Python3 example

```
import urllib.request

try:
    request = urllib.request.Request('http://httpstat.us/418', headers={'Accept': 'text/plain', 'User-Agent': ''})
    with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as page:
        print('success: ' + page.read().decode())
except urllib.error.HTTPError as httpError:
        error = httpError.read().decode()
        print('error: ' + error)
```