# Why does Python's urllib2.urlopen() raise an HTTPError for successful status codes?

Tags: python, urllib2, http-status-codes

According to [the urllib2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html#httperror),

> Because the default handlers handle redirects (codes in the 300 range), and codes in the 100-299 range indicate success, you will usually only see error codes in the 400-599 range.

And yet the following code

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

raises an HTTPError with code 201 (created):

```
ERROR    2011-08-11 20:40:17,318 __init__.py:463] HTTP Error 201: Created
```

**So why is `urllib2` throwing HTTPErrors on this successful request?**

It's not too much of a pain; I can easily extend the code to:

```
try:
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except HTTPError, e:
    if e.code == 201:
        # success! :)
    else:
        # fail! :(
else:
    # when will this happen...?
```

But this doesn't seem like the intended behavior, based on the documentation and the fact that I can't find similar questions about this odd behavior.

**Also, what should the `else` block be expecting?** If successful status codes are all interpreted as `HTTPError`s, then when does `urllib2.urlopen()` just return a normal file-like response object like all the `urllib2` documentation refers to?

Comment: It's really unusual to see response-codes between 201-299.  Not surprised urllib2 isn't handling them perfectly.

Comment: Am I missing something? 201 works fine for me...

Comment: @Santa, maybe you're using a non-standard handler, as per dcrosta's answer?

Comment: @Leopd: It actually does. Look at the current urllib2.py source in Python27\Lib, lines 511-3.

Comment: No, I used vanilla urllib2 with no modification.

Comment: @Santa hm, very strange. I tried this in Python 2.7 and, you're right, it works fine. I was using Python 2.5, so they probably gave it a saner default for 2.7.

Comment: The final `else` statement will be executed when the `try` block executes successfully - you can read it as `if exception: else:` if that helps.

Comment: @Sean yes, I'm aware. I asked about the `else` block because it seemed like every possible status code was a flavor of HTTPError, so I didn't understand when the `try` block would ever execute successfully. Apparently it was just for 200s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the actual library documentation mentions:

> For 200 error codes, the response object is returned immediately.
>
> For non-200 error codes, this simply passes the job on to the protocol_error_code handler methods, via OpenerDirector.error(). Eventually, urllib2.HTTPDefaultErrorHandler will raise an HTTPError if no other handler handles the error.

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#httperrorprocessor-objects

Answer (score 16):

You can write a custom `Handler` class for use with `urllib2` to prevent specific error codes from being raised as `HTTError`. Here's one I've used before:

```
class BetterHTTPErrorProcessor(urllib2.BaseHandler):
    # a substitute/supplement to urllib2.HTTPErrorProcessor
    # that doesn't raise exceptions on status codes 201,204,206
    def http_error_201(self, request, response, code, msg, hdrs):
        return response
    def http_error_204(self, request, response, code, msg, hdrs):
        return response
    def http_error_206(self, request, response, code, msg, hdrs):
        return response
```

Then you can use it like:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(self.BetterHTTPErrorProcessor)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally think it was a mistake and very nonintuitive for this to be the default behavior.
It's true that non-2XX codes imply a protocol level error, but turning that into an exception is too far (in my opinion at least).

In any case, I think the most elegant way to avoid this is:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
for processor in opener.process_response['https']: # or http, depending on what you're using
   if isinstance(processor, urllib.request.HTTPErrorProcessor): # HTTPErrorProcessor also for https
       opener.process_response['https'].remove(processor)
       break # there's only one such handler by default
response = opener.open('https://www.google.com')
```

Now you have the response object. You can check it's status code, headers, body, etc.