# Python urllib2 error 403

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am new to python and I have created a script for doing REST API from a log file, and for 3 weeks the code was running, but suddenly it just got error and it won't run. This is the code below :

```
import json
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

def sendRequest(line,action):
    req="https://api.emergingthreats.net/v1/ips/"+line.rstrip()+"/"+action
    request = Request(req)
    request.add_header("Authorization", "sec key")
    result = urlopen(request)
    return result
```

And this is the error I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vino/Desktop/all python files/malicious/IPChecking.py", line 31, in <module>
    result = sendRequest(line,"geoloc")
  File "/Users/vino/Desktop/all python files/malicious/IPChecking.py", line 8, in sendRequest
    result = urlopen(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

A solution would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: The server is returning HTTP error 403 (forbidden). This means that there is probably something wrong with your request. Nothing more can really be said about it without more information about the service. [Python urllib2: Reading content body even during HTTPError exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663790/python-urllib2-reading-content-body-even-during-httperror-exception) may be helpful.

Comment: Did you check the URL you're making call to? Seems like your IP or the whole external access to that URL is revoked. As HTTP 403 error is due to access right you have to the URL.

Comment: If it worked and then stopped, chances are something changed on the server. They reset your privileges so you are no longer authorized, perhaps?

Comment: @tripleee so is there any solution for this? Does this mean no problem with the code?

Comment: @Galen Thank you for the resource

Comment: The first comment from @Galen really summarizes things nicely.

Comment: @Galen I am quiet not sure what do I have to do to fix the issue, cause I am really new to python. So could you tell me what it is explained and how to fix the problem?

Comment: @RinaRiana This isn't really a python specific issue. Check how the REST API you are trying to use is supposed to be used. Also see the link in my previous comment. The body of the 403 response could provide you with useful information regarding what is wrong.